# Wix add entered path to registry

Tags: windows, wix, registry

I met a problem while adding entered by user path to registry.

Here are important parts of wix code.

Property declaration:

```
<Property Id="PathProp">C:\</Property>
```

Directory declaration:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="PathProp" Name="Name">
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Registry block:

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Path\To\Key" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
  <RegistryValue Name="UserSetPath" Value="[PathProp]" Type="string" />
</RegistryKey>
```

I have the dialog which pulls PathProp from user and I want entered value be in registry. But I see the default value ("C:\"). Is it possible to register exactly what user entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a experience in past, where installer properties set in UI mode were destroyed in Execute mode.

Reason:
Properties were not set "secure".
Wix properties have attribute secure="true". Use It.

Also if possible share the installer log with us,so we can have a look at it.

You can get log by using this command:

```
 <InstallerPath>/<InstallerName>.msi /l*v <LogPath>/InstallLog.txt
```

Comment: Great thanks, it using of secure variables helped. How I did miss it? :)

Comment: You can select suggestion as selected answer.